# ReferenceError: num1 is not defined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get the following error when running my simple script in JavaScript:

```
num1 is not defined
ReferenceError: num1 is not defined
at Object.twoNumberSum (/tester/program.js:8:2)
at Object.exports.run (/tester/json_wrapper.js:8:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (/tester/main.js:21:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js
```

The goal is to create a simple function (not optimized for time complexity) that takes in two parameters: an array of integers and a target sum. The result should return an array with any two distinct integer elements that sum up to the target sum.

Here's my code:

```
function twoNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        let num1 = array[i]
    };
        for (let j =1; j < array.length; j++){
            let num2 = array[j]
        };
    if (num1 + num2 === targetSum){
        console.log([num1, num2]);
    }
}
```

Any pointers here would be really appreciated because I'm not sure if it's a syntax issue or if I'm doing something that's not idiomatic for JavaScript.

Comment: `let` has a local scope.

Answer (score 3):

`let` defines the variable at the block scope so it only exists between the curly braces it lives in.

Your second loop needs to be inside the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code logic is incorrect, please see the updated version below

```js
function twoNumberSum(array, targetSum) {
  let num1 = 0
  let num2 = 0
  
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
    num1 = array[i]
    for (let j =1; j < array.length; j++){
      num2 = array[j]
      if (num1 + num2 === targetSum) {
        console.log(`num1 is ${num1}, num2 is ${num2}`)
        return
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log('cannot find num1 & num2')
}

twoNumberSum([1,2,3,4], 5)
```

Comment: I tried what you have above but it missed several test cases. So I adapted my code by nesting the for loops and using 'const' instead of 'let' to define the num1 and num2 variables.

Comment: @Codestudio I suggest you add your code to "code snippet", it is good because you and other viewers can play your code on the fly.